# App create a new instance when user click on app icon

Tags: android

I have app with few activities and i have a problem when user click on app icon in device launcher the app go to launcher activity and create a new instance of him
this happens only when i generate the apk.
this is the scenario to make it more clear:

Activity A -> move to -> Activity B
user minimize the app and click on app icon in launcher the activity A create a new instance.

this is my manifest

```
<application android:name=".MyApp" 
 android:allowBackup="false" 
 android:fullBackupContent="false" 
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
 android:label="@string/app_name" 
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name="com.myapp.ActivityA">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
//More activities
</application>
```

Comment: I used to see this a few years ago, I forget if it was a problem, or if it was a device manufacturer bug, or specific to an Android version. Have you tried on a different device / different version of Android?

Comment: Are you using  `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Acitiviy A (your launcher activity) put this in onCreate():

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && 
intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
    finish();
    return;       
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So this is a bug which has existed since API 1. Especially for some manufacturers like Samsung which use their own skin on Android. Suppose you have Activity A as the main activity and you open Activity B. You minimize the app and open the app from the launcher again. Android will start Activity A on top of the call stack for the app. So the new call stack is A->B->A. 
One workaround is to check for Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER category and Intent.ACTION_MAIN action in the intent that starts the initial Activity. If those two flags are present and the Activity is not at the root of the task (meaning the app was already running), call finish() on the initial Activity.

So in the `onCreate()` of the app, something like this

```
if (!isTaskRoot()
            && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            && getIntent().getAction() != null
            && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

        finish();
        return;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Ah someone posted while I was drafting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your launcher activity add in manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```